# Simple PHP RSVP Form

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to write what I thought would be a very simple PHP RSVP page for my (rapidly approaching) wedding.  I am learning PHP specifically for this task, and everything was going along just fine, until I hit a wall.  Below are high level steps of how I envision this working, along with the code I currently have written.  I really want to get this done this week, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

1. User puts in first and last name and hits "Search" button.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUwy3.jpg) is a an image of what the form looks like.  Below is the form's HTML.

   ```
           <form method = "post" action="rsvp.php">
               <span>First Name:</span><input type="text" name="firstName" value="Father">
               <span>Last Name </span><input type="text" name="lastName" value="Test">
               <input type="submit" name="search_submit" value="Search">
           </form>
   ```
2. On "Search" button press, query the database.  Below is the PHP code.

   ```
           if (isset($_POST['search_submit'])) {
               //Connect to the appropriate database.
               include 'dbconnect.php';
               //Set variables.
               $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
               $lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
               $query = "SELECT * FROM guests WHERE PartyID IN (SELECT PartyID FROM guests WHERE FirstName = '$firstName' AND LastName = '$lastName')";
               $result = mysqli_query($sql, $query);
               //If query doesn't return any results, give an error.
               if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
                   echo "<p id=" . '"' . "searchError" . '"' . ">Sorry, I couldn't find your name.  Try again.  If you still have an issue please send me an email.";
               } 
               //If query does return results, create a new form that allows guests to say if they are attending or not.
               else {
                   echo '<form method = "post" action="rsvp.php">
                   <span class="guestNames">Party Members</span>
                   <span class="radioButtons">Attending</span>
                   <span class="radioButtons">Not Attending</span>
                   <br/>
                   <br/>
                   ';
                   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                       echo '<span class="guestNames">' . $row['FirstName']
                       . ' '
                       . $row['LastName'] . '</span>
                        <input type="radio" class="radioButtons" name="' . $row['ID'] . '"value="yes">
                        <input type="radio" class="radioButtons" name="' . $row['ID'] . '"value="no"> 
                       <br />
                       ';
                   }
                   echo '<input type="submit" name="rsvp_submit" value="RSVP">
                   </form>';
               }

               mysqli_close($sql);
           }
   ```
3. Create another form.  Database returns names of all member's of user's party, along with radio button options of "Attending" or "Not Attending".  It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYoKK.jpg).
4. User selects appropriate radio button for each member and hits "RSVP" button.  This is where I am stuck.  See below...

   ```
               //This is the code that will eventually update the SQL database with the user's responses.
               if (isset($_POST['rsvp_submit'])) {
                   echo 'What do I do now?';
               }
   ```
5. On "RSVP" button press, run an appropriate update statement for each guest.

I really think I can figure out all of the data validation (making sure that every guest has a radio box selected) and update statements once I get past step 4.  I really just don't know how to approach this.  I have a lot of ideas about what should be done, but rather than be more long winded than I already have, I was hoping I could get some ideas from the experts here.  Again, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all, congratulations on your upcoming wedding! Can I make a suggestion though, and instead of stressing yourself over this, you might want to look at [this](http://thydzik.com/online-rsvp-form-and-database-with-php-javascript-and-mysql/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I actually just downloaded that right before I posted this. I did a quick scan through and saw a lot of stuff in there that I didn't really need. In my work I have had to go through someone else's HTML/CSS enough times to realize that it is usually easier to build something simple rather than stripping a more complex project to fit your needs. I was hoping to find something out here, and if that fails I would go the Hydzik route. I have also become very intrigued by PHP and intend to continue to use it after this project is complete.  Thanks again for the reply.

Comment: Believe me, I hear you. I've got at least a year before my wedding, and I'm going to be making a site for RSVPs, trying to hook in a registry, the whole she-bang. Until then, though, I'm perfectly content with throwing a WordPress site up and calling it a day. There are plenty of other things to stress out about!

Answer (score 0):

I think your form should be like:

```
<input type="radio" class="radioButtons" name="guess[' . $row['ID'] . ']" value="yes">
<input type="radio" class="radioButtons" name="guess[' . $row['ID'] . ']" value="no">
```

Then, in your php file:

```
if (isset($_POST['rsvp_submit'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['guess'] as $key => $value) {
         $attending = 0;
         $not_attending = 0;
         if ($value == 'yes') {
             $attending = 1;
         } else if ($value == 'no') {
             $not_attending = 1;
         }
         $sql = 'UPDATE guess set attending = $attending, not_attending = $not_attending WHERE id = $key;
         .....
    }
}
```